# Using another image with the use of a docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, python-requests

I had a question regarding docker-compose files and having an image use another image through a `requests.post` call? I am having trouble either connecting the two images together and/or accessing the images.

Here is what my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    cerberus:
        image: "ctpelok77/ibmresearchaiplanningsolver"
        ports:
            - "4501:4501"
    my-external-planner:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

I then use the following commands:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker run -it external-planner_my-external-planner
```

Inside the `my-external-command`, I use the following line `response = requests.post('http://cerberus:4501/planners/satisficing/seq-sat-cerberus', headers=headers, data=body_str)`; however, this gives me a

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='cerberus', port=4501): Max retries exceeded with 
url: /planners/satisficing/seq-sat-cerberus (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f90eeb04510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

I was wondering if I am not correctly connecting my images in the docker-compose or if I am incorrectly trying to access the images in my image?

Comment: Does it help to have the client image `depends_on: [cerberus]`?  That won't guarantee the server in the other container is actually running, but it will at least cause the host name to reliably resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to amend this issue by giving the services specific names and assigning them a shared network in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    my-ibm-planner:
        image: "ctpelok77/ibmresearchaiplanningsolver"
        ports:
            - "4501:4501"
        container_name: "ibm-container"
        networks:
            - network-planner
        tty: true
    my-external-planner:
        image: "docker.sift.net/tbessho/external-planner"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        networks:
            - network-planner
        container_name: "ext-plan"
        tty: true
networks:
    network-planner:
        name: network-planner
```

along with changing the python script to use the following line:

```py
response = requests.post('http://ibm-container:4501/planners/satisficing/seq-sat-cerberus')
```